# How to join bluetooth pan as client with windows uwp api?

Tags: c#, networking, bluetooth, uwp

I want to setup a bluetooth PAN between a linux device and a Windows 10 desktop/phone. I have configured the linux device to act as group ad-hoc network controller (GN). Now I want to connect the windows 10 device as client (PANU).

I have created an uwp app which is able to scan for devices. 
Device pairing is also no problem with the API. But after the pairing I have to manually establish the connection to the PAN (over system controls -> bluetooth pan devices).

Is there a way to manage that with the API?

Comment: Have you tried `BluetoothLEDevice.FromIdAsync()` ?

Comment: The device isn't Bluetooth LE compatible, so I can't use it.

Comment: What about `BluetoothDevice.FromIdAsync()` ?

Comment: yes sry i should write it in the other comment. I use `await BluetoothDevice.FromIdAsync(device.Id)`
and if it successful i ask for available services. so i get this `ServiceCapabilities = NetworkingService`